# How to get Two Eclipse Dynamic Web Projects Set up on WebLogic with a Different Port for Each Project?

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, port

We currently have one dynamic web project (our main web application) already setup on WebLogic.  We now need to set up a new dynamic web project specifically for web services.  Our main web application was design with the context root being just `/` and would take years to change it to something else.  So this leaves us with the alternative of making the new project listen to a different port.

I first looked into virtual hosts, but could not find out how to change the virtual host ports.  Then I looked into creating a new server, but couldn't figure out how to get eclipse to see two servers on the same domain.

We have WebLogic 11gR1, PatchSet 2 and OEPE Eclipse 3.6.1 bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.  I had to use Eclipse to create a new domain.  The only downside to this is that I had to re-setup the connection pools, which is most fortunately a one-time deal.